# memory limit exceeded in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A)
{
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    map<int, int>ma;
    int m;
    for (int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
        ma[A[i]] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
        ma[A[i]]++;
    if (A.size() == 1 && A[0] == 0)
        return 1;
    if (ma[A[0]] == (A.size() + 1))
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ma[A[i]]>2 && ma[A[i]]>0)
        {
            m = A.size() - (i + 1) - (ma[A[i]] - 2);
            ma[A[i]] = -1;

        }
        if (ma[A[i]] == 2)
            m = A.size() - (i + 1);
        if (m == A[i])
        {

            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Given an integer array, find if an integer p exists in the array such that the number of integers greater than p  in the array equals to p
If such an integer is found return 1 else return -1.
A is the vector input by the user.

I am writing this program in interviewBit.com
It is showing **MEMORY LIMIT EXCEEDED** How can I optimise this code, I have tried using array, vector,unordered_map instead of map then it is showing segmentation fault

**THE ARRAY CAN HAVE REPEATED ELEMENT AND NEGATIVE INTEGERS ALSO**
I have used map for keeping track how many times each element is repeated

Comment: If you are looking for feedback on working code, consider posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: you should not ask this question here !

Comment: why do you need map? After sorting start from end. Last value has no members bigger than it - so it should be 0 to match condition. Next one should be 1, next should be 2... Go till you find match or rich index 0.

Comment: What is the memory limit?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky map is used to keep track of the repeating element if any

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this problem is how do you figure out how many items are greater than a given value in the array, without using any additional memory.

This is easy to do once the array is ordered: subtracting the current one-based position from array size gives you the answer.

Therefore, you can solve this problem by ordering the array, and then walking it once, and checking each position for `a[i] == a.size()-i-1`.

**Note:** The problem may become a little harder if you allow equal numbers in the array. In this case you need to continue walking the array up after detecting a start of an equal range.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use map. After the sort; just go from the end of the array, count elements and compare this count with the upcoming element.

Update: even better - sort the array in the descending order and check if any element is equal to its index.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Optimizing the code by not using additional memory - how does it not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Combining a nth_element with a binary search might get the result in O(N) in average (~2N+logN).

Totally untested code ahead:

```
auto start = v.begin();
auto last  = v.end();

while(start != last) {

    auto half = (std::distance(start, last)/2);
    auto median = start + half;
    std::nth_element(start, median, last);
    auto med = *median;

    if (med > half) {
      if (*median > std::distance(median, v.end()))
        return -1; // early out
      last = median;
    } else {
      if (*median < std::distance(median, v.end()))
        return -1; // early out
      start = median;
    }     
}

if (*start == std::distance(start, v.end())
  return 1;
return -1;
```

Todo: test, test and check for off by one